# Upper case conversion and digit summing

Tags: c, character

My programs goal: Only the letters will be printed out nothing else. The program will continue until the return is received at which time the sum of the digits will be printed on the next line. Use getch not getchar...
It's suppose to only print the uppercase letter. I'm just gonna fail it because no one would ever use getch() :(

example user input: What was entered: a9 wF23’;/4i
What gets printed: What the line actually shows: aA9wWFiI
The sum of the digits is: 18

I'm curious as to why I am getting an echo? It prints out the letter entered 3 times. Now I suppose if both my if's are true it would print twice?...

***Update thanks for the input everyone I will update in the morning. Out of caffine :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int digitconversion (int sum, int c);
int caseconversion (int c);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    char c;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Please enter a character or characters ");
    c = getch();


    while (c !='\r') {
        c = getch();

        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            digitconversion (sum, c);

        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') 
        putchar(c);
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        {
            putchar(c);
            c = caseconversion (c);
            putchar(c);
        }
        c = getch();

    }

    printf("The sum of the digits is %d\n", sum);       
    return 0;
}

int caseconversion (int c)
{  char u;
    u = c - (char)32;
    return u;
}
//function converts letter to number
int digitconversion (int sum, int c)
{

        sum += (int)(c - '0');

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `if (c >= 'A' && c >= 'Z')` Always true for lower-case letters. Never true for uppercase letters except `Z`. You meant `<= 'Z'`

Comment: `sum` will always be 0.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: ohhhhhh that is such a dumb mistake

Comment: Just a typo, happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, use standard functions to illustrate an example (`getchar` instead of `getch`).

There are a lot of bugs in your code:

```
while (c !='\r') {
```

must be

```
while (c !='\n') {
```

---

```
if (c >= 'A' && c >= 'Z')
```

must be

```
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
```

---

```
digitconversion (sum, c);
```

must be

```
sum = digitconversion (sum, c);
```

You are using 3 calls to `getch` (one is enough)

You are including `ctype.h` but using your own functions, why? Use `toupper(c)` and `isdigit(c)`.

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digitconversion(int c);
int caseconversion(int c);

int main(void) 
{
    int c, sum = 0;

    printf("Please enter a character or characters ");
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            sum += digitconversion(c);
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') 
            putchar(c);
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            c = caseconversion(c);
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe sum of the digits is %d\n", sum);   
    return 0;
}

int caseconversion(int c)
{
    return c - 32; /* This is not true under EBCDIC encoding, use toupper() */
}

int digitconversion(int c)
{
    return c - '0';
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a character or characters abc1234ABC
ABCABC
The sum of the digits is 10
```

Comment: Ok thank you for the input!I am actually not aloud to do ctype.h functions should have mentioned that.

Comment: Wow I also never came across in my book being able to use return with a calculation in it. Neato!

Comment: Unfortunetly this program does not print example user input: What was entered: a9 wF23’;/4i
What gets printed: What the line actually shows: aA9wWFiI

Comment: It has to use getch() and not getchar() thanks for the input though

Comment: Then replace `c = getchar()` with `c = getch()`, where is the problem?

Comment: Just my problem solving skills apologies